# Jquery: Selector ID undefined into for-loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, syntax, selector

The console.log(a) give me undefined, but the console.log(b) give the result that i want.

This is the js file.

```
            for(i=0; i<$info['numeroEquipo']; i++){
                var txt0 = "<div id='editEquipo"+i+"' class='col-sm-3'><div class='form-group label-floating'><div class='form-group form-inline'>  <label class='custom-control-label'><p class='formatoTextolabel'>Equipo "+i+"</p></label> <button type='button' class='boton btn btn-light btn-sm bmd-btn-icon' value='-' onclick=\"$('#editEquipo"+i+"').remove(); return false;\"><i class='material-icons'>remove_circle_outline</i></button></div><div id='editSelectEquipo"+i+"'></div></div></div>";
                $("#editCampoEquipo").append(txt0);
                $("#editSelectEquipo"+i+"").load("php/selectEquipo2.php?var="+i+"", function(){
                    a =  $("#test"+i+"").attr("id");
                    console.log(a);
                    b = 
                    $("#test0").attr("id");
                    console.log(0);
                      });
```

This is the selectEquipo2.php file.

```
<?php
    include 'datos.php';
    $i = $_GET['var'];
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$bd","$user", "$pass");
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $pdo->query("CALL selectEquipo");
        $x = $stmt->rowCount();

        echo "<select id='test".$i."' class='selectEquipo2 form-control'>";
        echo "<option selected=''></option>";
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

            echo "<option class='formatoTextoinput' id=".$row['IDEQUIPO'].">".$row['NOMBREEQUIPO']."</option>";          
       }
        echo '</select>
        </div>  ';
?>
```

Comment: You’re not logging b. You’re logging the number 0 instead of the variable b.

Comment: If the JavaScript is run before the PHP, the elements will be undefined. Make sure the JavaScript is run after the PHP.

Comment: You have a big problem making `i` a global variable. The loop will be long completed before the load callbacks run

Comment: And creating an id selector for jQuery to return the same id doesn't make any sense